# Laravel sail test works but vendor/bin/phpunit doesn't

Tags: laravel, phpunit, github-actions, laravel-sail

I've setup a work flow using github actions and when it gets to this command there are 3 failed tests

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

But during this command on my machine they all pass

```
sail artisan test
```

The github workflow is getting this error

> Expected response status code [200] but received 403. Failed asserting
> that 200 is identical to 403.

This is one of the tests it's failing

```
$user = User::factory()->create();
$consumer = Consumer::factory()->create();

$response = $this->actingAs($user)->getJson('api/consumer/show/' . $consumer->id);
$response->assertOk();
$response->assertJson([
    'data' => [
        'id' => $consumer->id,
        'name' => $consumer->name,
        'email' => $consumer->email,
    ],
]);
```

This test is very similar to other tests and they don't have any issues. Is there a way to run a sail setup on github instead? Or has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: You have something wrong in there, maybe it is running locally because you have something on your database that exists (is set) when you run this, but on github it is not set, hence the error. Another possibility is that you have something set on your local `.env` that is not when github runs. Add `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` and run it again on github, you should get the full exception then producing `403`.

Comment: On github actions you're doing `vendor/bin/phpunit` and locally, well, through sail, you're doing `php artisan test`. Remember the phrase "it works on my machine"? Here you go. Log in to sail, something like `sail exec app` and mimic your exact setup on github actions. `.env`, database, phpunit.xml, everything. Now run your test the same way you do on github actions

Comment: @UnderDog absolutely valid point! but remember that, most of the people (specially new ones) do not use Sail on CI/CD because, sometimes, it is harder to set up than just running a single command to have it all running. If that is the case, author would not have `sail artisan test`, so we have to wait on him to let us know how is he setting up the CI/CD

Comment: I sorted it. There are some default settings I require in my .env file to make some middleware work so once I updated that file the tests worked fine